# C# VSTO Call async method from other add-in, and await for response

Tags: c#, asynchronous, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I've got a running Outlook add-in, which has an exposed async function, that returns a

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<String> object.
```

When I call this method from another application, I get the following exception:

```
System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'
```

My Outlook async functions job is to:

1. Send And Receive new emails
2. If there were new emails coming in, then process them via the ItemAdd event
3. If processing is done, then create a report of them
4. Return this report to my other application

**How I call the async method from my host application:**

```
public static async void GetOutlookReport() 
{
    object addInName = "myOutlookAddIn";
    var outlookApplication = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");
    Office.COMAddIn addIn = outlookApplication.COMAddIns.Item(ref addInName);
    if (addIn != null)
    {
        String Report = await addIn.Object.myAsyncOutlookFunction("parameter1"); //failes here
        //do whatever with report...
    }
}
```

**How the method is declared in the Outlook addin:**

-My Ribbon.cs class file has the following:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IAddInUtilities
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<String> myAsyncOutlookFunction(String Param1);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class AddInUtilities : StandardOleMarshalObject,
IAddInUtilities
{
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<String> myAsyncOutlookFunction(String Param1)
    {
        String x = await myAsyncOutlookFunctionDefined(Param1);
        return x;
    }
}
```

-Implementation of myAsyncOutlookFunctionDefined:

```
public static async Task<String> myAsyncOutlookFunctionDefined(String Param1)
{
    try
    {
        //try to get all new emails in
        await CallSendAndReceive(); //function that simply calls NameSpace.SendAndReceive();

        //after SendAndReceive finished, the ItemAdd events should run (code not implemented yet)
        //after ItemAdd events have finished we create the report

        String Report = CreateReport(); //this function is irrelevant right now
        return Report;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Is it even possible, to wait from my host application until

- Outlook finishes with the SendAndReceive
- Runs all the ItemAdd events on the inbox folder
- Do my own processing
- Send back a report to the host application via a string form ?

The idea would be, to run the function for a maximum of 30 seconds, if it didn't finish with getting the emails, and processing them to create the report, then just return an empty string.

I can't continue with this development, if I can't get a response from the async function, by calling it from the other application (host).

**NOTE:**

Just for fun, I added a button to my Outlook add-in, that simulates the same action. When I click the button, I am able to call the same myAsyncOutlookFunction, however, I don't call it via the Office.COMAddIn object, but directly. It runs smoothly, meaning the System.Threading.Tasks.Task object has the correct data.

This kind of proves, that calling it via the exposed class it the source of the problem...

Answer (score 0):

The missing GetAwaiter() call seems to indicate that the framework version the calling code is running on does not support async/await. Test invoking the method using pure TPL (not using async/await keywords).